# Alternative to SUMPRODUCT part 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For two durations that are in the same row (just different columns) and two whole numbers that are also in the same row, I'm trying to compute the equivalent formula as in [my previous question](//superuser.com/q/1335711) which had the values on separate rows.

[image]

I tried to use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(duration1,duration2,number1,number2)/sum(number1,number2)
```

but I'm not getting the correct answer as when they are in different rows (but the same columns).

I also can't figure out how to add in the date as a criteria like I did in my previous question.

You may download a sample workbook from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_RRI2Kr00ZQ2K9h7TgICAMkkuRT4AFiq).

Comment: `SUM(E4*D4,I4*J4)/SUM(D4,I4)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are having problems because you misunderstand exactly how the `SUMPRODUCT()` function works.

What it does is to multiply **all** the arguments' respective elements together, and ***then*** sum the resulting array.

Take the following as an example:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3, B1:B3, C1:C3, D1:D3)
```

The two steps in evaluating this formula would be:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT({A1*B1*C1*D1; A2*B2*C2*D2; A3*B3*C3*D3})
```

```dart
=A1*B1*C1*D1 + A2*B2*C2*D2 + A3*B3*C3*D3
```

For your particular case, what you actually need to do is to get the sum of *two* sumproducts:

```dart
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(duration1,number1),SUMPRODUCT(duration2,number2))/SUM(number1,number2)
```

For your supplied sample workbook, the formula in `F5` would be:

```dart
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT('CHAT US Raw Data'!I6,'CHAT US Raw Data'!P6),SUMPRODUCT('CHAT US Raw Data'!T6,'CHAT US Raw Data'!U6))/SUM('CHAT US Raw Data'!I6,'CHAT US Raw Data'!T6)
```

Note that this is equivalent to explicitly performing the multiplications inside the `SUMPRODUCT()` function and just using the function to sum the resulting array (as was done in the answer to the part 1 question):

```dart
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(duration1*number1),SUMPRODUCT(duration2*number2))/SUM(number1,number2)
```

with the actual formula in `F5` being:

```dart
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT('CHAT US Raw Data'!I6*'CHAT US Raw Data'!P6),SUMPRODUCT('CHAT US Raw Data'!T6*'CHAT US Raw Data'!U6))/SUM('CHAT US Raw Data'!I6,'CHAT US Raw Data'!T6)
```

---

This formula still needs to be adapted to check for matching dates (and the first matching student names if still applicable) as per your previous questions.

For the dividend we can just add an extra date check term.

The divisor `SUM()` function, however, needs to be modified before a date check can be added. We need a sum of two sumif functions (assuming that you wish to extend the formula for multiple rows):

```dart
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT((date1=date)*duration1*number1),SUMPRODUCT((date2=date)*duration2*number2))
/SUM(SUMIF(date1,date,number1),SUMIF(date2,date,number2))
```

with the actual formula in `F5` being:

```dart
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(('CHAT US Raw Data'!H6=E5)*'CHAT US Raw Data'!I6*'CHAT US Raw Data'!P6),SUMPRODUCT(('CHAT US Raw Data'!S6=E5)*'CHAT US Raw Data'!T6*'CHAT US Raw Data'!U6))/SUM(SUMIF('CHAT US Raw Data'!H6,E5,'CHAT US Raw Data'!I6),SUMIF('CHAT US Raw Data'!S6,E5,'CHAT US Raw Data'!T6))
```

The alternative to manually performing the multiplications inside the `SUMPRODUCT()` (with the resulting implicit boolean coercion), would be to coerce the date checks explicitly to ones and zeroes with the double negative unary operator. For example, `(date1=date)`would become `--(date1=date)`:

```dart
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(--(date1=date),duration1,number1),SUMPRODUCT(--(date2=date),duration2,number2))
/SUM(SUMIF(date1,date,number1),SUMIF(date2,date,number2))
```

with the actual formula:

```dart
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(--('CHAT US Raw Data'!H6=E5),'CHAT US Raw Data'!I6,'CHAT US Raw Data'!P6),SUMPRODUCT(--('CHAT US Raw Data'!S6=E5),'CHAT US Raw Data'!T6,'CHAT US Raw Data'!U6))/SUM(SUMIF('CHAT US Raw Data'!H6,E5,'CHAT US Raw Data'!I6),SUMIF('CHAT US Raw Data'!S6,E5,'CHAT US Raw Data'!T6))
```

---

As a final note, there are equivalent sumproduct versions for the sumif divisor.

For example,

```dart
SUM(SUMIF(date1,date,number1),SUMIF(date2,date,number2))
```

is equivalent to

```dart
SUM(SUMPRODUCT((date1=date)*number1),SUMPRODUCT((date2=date)*number2))
```

as well as

```dart
SUM(SUMPRODUCT(--(date1=date),number1),SUMPRODUCT(--(date2=date),number2))
```